# Numbering tables where multiple instances count as one table XSLT 3.0

Tags: count, xslt-3.0

Given this XML:

```
    <preliminaryRqmts>
    <!-- Table 1 -->
    <reqCondGroup>
          <reqCondNoRef>
                <reqCond>Lorem ipsum</reqCond>
          </reqCondNoRef>
    </reqCondGroup>
    <!-- Table 2 -->
    <reqPersons>
          <person man="A">
                <personCategory personCategoryCode="Chemical technician"/>
                <personSkill skillLevelCode="sk02"/>
                <trade>Cleaner</trade>
                <estimatedTime unitOfMeasure="h">1,0</estimatedTime>
          </person>
    </reqPersons>
    <reqPersons>
          <person man="B">
                <personCategory personCategoryCode="Operator"/>
                <personSkill skillLevelCode="sk02"/>
                <trade>Painter</trade>
                <estimatedTime unitOfMeasure="h">1,0</estimatedTime>
          </person>
    </reqPersons>
    <reqPersons>
          <person man="B">
                <personCategory personCategoryCode="Operator"/>
                <personSkill skillLevelCode="sk03"/>
                <trade>Rider</trade>
                <estimatedTime unitOfMeasure="h">0,8</estimatedTime>
          </person>
    </reqPersons>
    <!-- Table 3 -->
    <reqSafety>
      <noSafety/>
   </reqSafety>
</preliminaryRqmts>
<taskDefinition>
    <task>
       <taskDescr>
          <simplePara>Lorem ipsum</simplePara>
       </taskDescr>
    </task>
    <preliminaryRqmts>
       <!-- Table 4 -->
       <reqCondGroup>
          <noConds/>
       </reqCondGroup>
       <!-- Table 5 -->
       <reqPersons>
          <person man="A">
             <personCategory personCategoryCode="Basic user"/>
             <trade>Operator</trade>
             <estimatedTime unitOfMeasure="h">0,3</estimatedTime>
          </person>
       </reqPersons>
       <!-- Table 6 -->
       <reqSpares>
          <noSpares/>
       </reqSpares>
    </preliminaryRqmts>
</taskDefinition>
```

I have to include the Table number when outputting the table title. `<reqPersons>` may have multiple siblings but they are counted as one table. So in the XML provided, the first three `reqPersons` are counted as one table, Table 2. `reqPersons` is not a required element so there could be `<preliminaryRqmts>` without any `<reqPersons>`.

I am having trouble getting the correct table numbering for `reqPersons` when there is more than one `preliminaryRqmts` with a `reqPersons`. Originally I had `<xsl:value-of select="if(preceding::reqPersons) then 1 else 0"/>`. This fails when there are multiple  `preliminaryRqmts/reqPersons`.

Here are the templates for the table numbering and reqPersons. Only the first `reqPersons` gets a title and table number. Any `following-siblings::reqPersons` are ignored in the table count. I need help with fixing `<xsl:variable name="countPer" select="count(ancestor-or-self::preliminaryRqmts/reqPersons[1])"/>`, the rest of the numbering is working properly.

```
    <xsl:template match="reqPersons[1]">
      <fo:block>
        <xsl:text>Table&#xa0;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:call-template name="number-tables"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xa0;&#xa0;Required persons</xsl:text>
      </fo:block>
      <fo:table>
        <xsl:call-template name="reqPersonTableBody"/>
      </fo:table>
    </fo:block>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="reqPersons">
    <fo:block>
      <fo:table>
        <xsl:call-template name="reqPersonTableBody"/>
      </fo:table>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="reqPersonTableBody">
    <fo:table-column column-number="1" column-width="33%"/>
    <fo:table-column column-number="2" column-width="33%"/>
    <fo:table-column column-number="3" column-width="33%"/>
    <fo:table-header>
      <fo:table-row>
        <fo:table-cell>
          <fo:block>Person</fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell>
          <fo:block>Category</fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell>
          <fo:block>Skill level</fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
      </fo:table-row>
    </fo:table-header>
    <fo:table-body>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="personnel | person"/>
    </fo:table-body>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="number-tables">
    <xsl:variable name="countreqCondTables" select="count(preceding::reqCondGroup|preceding::reqSupportEquips|preceding::reqSupplies|preceding::reqSpares|preceding::reqTechInfoGroup)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="countPer" select="count(ancestor-or-self::preliminaryRqmts/reqPersons[1])"/>
    <xsl:variable name="countSelfPer" select="count(ancestor-or-self::reqPersons[1])"/>

    <xsl:variable name="countSelf" select="count(ancestor-or-self::table|ancestor-or-self::reqCondGroup|ancestor-or-self::reqSupportEquips|ancestor-or-self::reqSupplies|
      ancestor-or-self::reqSpares|ancestor-or-self::reqTechInfoGroup)"/>
    
    <xsl:value-of select="$countPer+$countSelf+$countSelfPer+$countreqCondTables"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: It is not clear what other code you have that creates "table"s for the input as you haven't shown that code. Does that code exist and does it create the right number of tables and you could just number them after having them created?

Comment: @Martin Honnen I've added the templates for reqPersons and the table numbering. The other table templates are similar and the right number of tables are being created. I just need help with getting the table numbering correct for reqPersons. Is there anything else I should add?

Comment: So you have `xsl:template match="reqPersons"` and in that template you create a result element `fo:table`. If all `reqPersons` input elements are processed, it would map each of them to a `fo:table`. Are you trying to number those `fo:table`s? `<xsl:variable name="countTables" select="count(preceding::table)"/>` seems to suggest the input XML also has `table` elements, so, at least for me, it is not clear which elements you want to count, input tables or result tables.

Comment: Anyway, if your current code creates the `fo:table`s you want and you need to number them, use two steps, the first creates the `fo:table`s and stores its result in a variable, the second step processes the variable with a template that uses `xsl:number` in a template matching `fo:table` to output the right number you want/need.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I fixed the templates, they were not clear. There are two templates for `reqPersons` since only the first `reqPersons` gets a title and is included in the table count. The `following-sibling::reqPersons` are not included in the table count. I'm having trouble getting the correct numbering of `reqPersons` when there is more than one `preliminaryRqmts` that has a `reqPersons`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check whether you can use `xsl:number count="some pattern matching the elements you want to count" level="any"` e.g. in XSLT 3

```
<xsl:param name="table-count-pattern" static="yes" as="xs:string" select="'preliminaryRqmts/reqCondGroup | preliminaryRqmts/reqPersons[1] | preliminaryRqmts/reqSafety | preliminaryRqmts/reqSpares'"/>

<xsl:template _match="{$table-count-pattern}">
    <xsl:comment>computed table <xsl:number _count="{$table-count-pattern}" level="any"/></xsl:comment>
    <xsl:next-match/>
</xsl:template>
```

seems to give the numbers you have in your comments output in another comment. Of course, you don't want to output a comment, you want to output that number in your `fo:block` but you can obviously adapt the above suggestion easily. If needed, if you have lots of different templates for all the elements that need to output that count, put the above template in a mode with e.g. `mode="count"`, and in your other templates, where you need to number, use e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="count"/>`. You will probably want to remove the `xsl:next-match` in that case.

Comment: thank you, I put the `<xsl:number>` in the table numbering template, I'm trying to make it work. What is the underscore in `_match` and `_count`?

Comment: These are shadow attributes to use the static parameter so that the pattern can be defined once in a central place and be reused for match and count attributes without having to retype or repeat the same code.